# Slideshow button underline and fade out animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently using a default shape of slideshow indicator which is a dot/bullet shaped indicator.

Questions :

- Everytime my mouse hover on the next button, it will display a underline below the button. Is there a way to remove it ?
- And Is there is a way to change the fade animation into Fade Out ?

Because of time constraint I don't have much time to make a slideshow from scratch so I just grab this code mostly from W3School sites and used it as it is.

Here's a part of the HTML code :

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
var timer = null;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  clearTimeout(timer);
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  clearTimeout(timer);
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n == undefined) {
    n = ++slideIndex
  }
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
  timer = setTimeout(showSlides, 4000);
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0
}

.mySlides {
  display: none
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}


/* Slideshow container */

.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}


/* Next & previous buttons */

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}


/* Position the "next button" to the right */

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}


/* Caption text */

.text {
  background-color: #424242;
  color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 0.8;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Number text (1/3 etc) */

.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}


/* The dots/bullets/indicators */

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}


/* Fading animation */

.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .1
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .1
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}


/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */

@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev,
  .next,
  .text {
    font-size: 11px
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">
  <h1 class="page_title">IR</h1>
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <a href="/ir/library/results_briefing/"></a>
    <img src="/ir/images/slider_img02.jpg" alt="A" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">A</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <a href="/ir/investment/event/"></a>
    <img src="/ir/images/slider_img01.jpg" alt="A" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">A</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <a href="/ir/library/"></a>
    <img src="/ir/images/slider_img03.jpg" alt="IRA" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">IRA</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <a href="/ir/business/message/"></a>
    <img src="/ir/images/slider_img04.jpg" alt="A" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">A</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <a href="/ir/calendar/"></a>
    <img src="/ir/images/slider_img05.jpg" alt="A" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">A</div>
  </div>

  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(5)"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: what browser do you use??

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce that as the CSS alignment is a bit out of place. But my first guess would be to use the following for the underline removal.

```
.next, .prev { text-decoration: none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var slideIndex = 1;
    var timer = null;
    showSlides(slideIndex);

    function plusSlides(n) {
clearTimeout(timer);
showSlides(slideIndex += n);
    }

    function currentSlide(n) {
clearTimeout(timer);
showSlides(slideIndex = n);
    }

    function showSlides(n) {
var i;
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
if (n==undefined){n = ++slideIndex}
if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
  slides[i].style.display = "none";
}
for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
  dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
}
slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
timer = setTimeout(showSlides, 4000);
    }
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box}
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
body {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; margin:0}
.mySlides {display: none}
img {vertical-align: middle;}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
max-width: 1000px;
position: relative;
margin: auto;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
cursor: pointer;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
width: auto;
padding: 16px;
margin-top: -22px;
color: black;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 18px;
transition: 0.6s ease;
border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
text-decoration: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
right: 0;
border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}


/* Caption text */
.text {
background-color: #424242;
color: #ffffff;
opacity: 0.8;
font-size: 15px;
padding: 8px 12px;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
color: #f2f2f2;
font-size: 12px;
padding: 8px 12px;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
cursor: pointer;
height: 15px;
width: 15px;
margin: 0 2px;
background-color: #bbb;
border-radius: 50%;
display: inline-block;
transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {

-webkit-animation: fade 2s; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
       -moz-animation: fade 2s; /* Firefox < 16 */
        -ms-animation: fade 2s; /* Internet Explorer */
         -o-animation: fade 2s; /* Opera < 12.1 */
            animation: fade 2s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
from {opacity: 0}
to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
from {opacity: 0}
to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
.prev, .next,.text {font-size: 11px}
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">
        <h1 class="page_title">IR</h1>
    <div class="mySlides fade">
        <a href="/ir/library/results_briefing/"></a>
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x30" alt="A" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text">A</div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
        <a href="/ir/investment/event/"></a>
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x30" alt="A" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text">A</div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
        <a href="/ir/library/"></a>
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x30" alt="IRA" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text">IRA</div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
        <a href="/ir/business/message/"></a>
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x30" alt="A" style="width:100%">
        <div class="text">A</div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
        <a href="/ir/calendar/"></a>
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x30" alt="A" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text">A</div>
    </div>

    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

    </div>
    <br>

    <div style="text-align:center">
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span>
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(5)"></span>
    </div>
```

this should work